# jQuery DOCTYPE CSS bug with IE 6 & 7 - Quirks Mode

Tags: jquery, doctype, html-table

Ok strange behavior when it should work:

The problem is if I don't declare a doctype the CSS works in IE 6 & 7 but if I declare the DOCTYPE it doesn't work. Why???

jQuery:

```
$('tr:first-child').children().css({
   'width': settings.minWidth + 'px',
   'height': settings.tableHeaderHeight + 'px',
   'overflow': 'hidden',
   'white-space': 'nowrap',
   'color': 'blue'
});
```

[HTML w/ DOCTYPE](http://jsbin.com/ajeve) - Please view in Firefox and IE 6 & 7 to see the table header difference

[HTML wo/ DOCTYPE](http://jsbin.com/ajiwo) - Please view in Firefox and IE 6 & 7 to see the table header difference

DOCTYPE I'm declaring:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

So after a helpful comment I found that quirks mode is being used when I don't add the DOCTYPE, which is the CSS effect I want but with a DOCTYPE, Ugh!!!

any work arounds? Suggestions?

Solution, YEAH!!!

jQuery

```
// This adds a div tag around the table header text 
//  - IE white-space bug in standard mode
$('table.className tr th').wrapInner(
  "<div class='ie_correct_header_whitespace'></div>"
);
```

CSS

```
.ie_correct_header_whitespace {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Which DOCTYPE are you declaring?

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want the headers to just say "Cell" or are you attempting to make the headers all stay on one line even if they are larger than the header cell?

For FF I see exactly what I would expect: the header text is cut off and doesn't wrap.

For IE 7 w/ the doc type I see exactly what I would expect and its the same in FF.

for IE 7 w/o the doc type I see unexpected behavior, but that is because IE w/o a doc type defaults to quirks mode.

Comment: I would like the overflow and the white-space CSS tags to work as well as declaring a doctype

Comment: can I force quicrks mode for IE browsers? w/ jQuery? other?

Comment: FF w/ and w/o doctype works exactly as IE 6/7 w/ doctype. IE 6/7 w/o doc type works differently. Which do you want?

Comment: I would like everything to work with a DOCTYPE as Firefox does. The table header text should be in one line with the overflow hiding the remaining text. So you should just see the start of the table header title with the rest hidden, NOT stacked in the same cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I seriously advise you to make it work in standards mode. Relying on quirks mode to make any layout 'just work' is not a very healthy approach.

You can wrap your content in a block element, let's say a DIV element, and then put your DIV in your table header.
Overflow and width should be respected that way in standards mode, giving you the desired effect.